# Smartgwt RestDataSource with SpringMVC and cross-client

Tags: json, spring-mvc, cors, smartgwt, same-origin-policy

After a lot of work, I have an existing back-end web services application that is powered by Spring-RS, Spring MVC, Spring controllers, and these controllers user Jackson within the Spring framework to convert responses to JSON.

Here is part of the WEB-INF/myproject-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
          <property name="objectMapper">
             <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">

                     <property name="dateFormat">
                        <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
                            <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="yyyy-MM-dd"></constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                     </property>
             </bean>
          </property>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
  <property name="messageConverters">
      <list>
        <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter" />
      </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

This web-services app works great!  I can deploy the WAR to my local tomcat, and it deploys fine.  I can unit test he controller to make sure the URL is correct and the web-app is correct configured within Spring.  I can hit the URL and get JSON data back exactly as I expected it to.   The url is:

```
http://mylocalhost/myproject/invoices/invoiceId/1
```

returns 1 invoice.

Now, I am running a SmartGWT web-app, the free version, and I have a RestDataScource controller.   I have written many SmartGWT web-apps before, and these apps were all inclusive: entities, dao's, service layer, controllers, and datasources.  With this, there was no cross-client issues at all provided the controllers and the datasources were within the same app.  And I am not against doing that again, but I want to try to separate them apart.

I just recently saw that this does not work!!!  With my SmartGWT web-app running locally within Jetty for development mode.  The starting URL is:

```
     http://mylocalhost:8888/myapp
```

And when this tries to call the back-end on

```
    http://mylocalhost:8080/my-ws, then my listgrid gives me a warning message.
```

If I can just add the one line:  RPCManager.setAllowCrossDomainCalls(true);
Do I add this within my RESTDataSource?   Where do I add this to?     And will it really just make everything work?   Is there anything else I need to add?

So, I was looking at XJSONDataSource and I saw that I needed to make a few changes to my RestDataSource to convert it to a XJsonDataSource.   There is some great information here with another posting and they suggested adding:

```
   // Where do I put this line?   the controller or the datasource
   String callbackString = request.getParameter("callback");

   // Where do I put this code?  the controller or the datasource
   response.setContentType("text/X-JSON");
   response.getWriter().write( callbackString + " ( " + JSONstring + " ) " );
   response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

I am not sure where this code goes, so I need some extra help there.   As far as the controller goes, here is part of what it looks like:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/invoiceId", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
        InvoiceDetailDTO getContactTypeByUserId(@RequestBody String invoiceNumber)
     {
         InvoiceDetailDTO invoiceDetailDto = invoiceService.getInvoiceDetail(invoiceNumber);

        // invoiceDetailDto is automatically converted to JSON by Spring
        return invoiceDetailDto;
     }
```

In the code above with "request" and "response" have to go into the controller, how do I go about that?

Ultimately, I'd love to just use my RestDataSource and tweak it to work the way I want it to, and ignore any of these cross-site issues.   If I do need to use XJSONDataSource, I just need some real good examples, and an example on how to tweak my controllers if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RPCManager.setAllowCrossDomainCalls(true);` should be called during early stages of initialization (e.g.- `onModuleLoad()`).

`getContactTypeByUserId` might have to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a response header with proper value.
Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.
Based on http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=15487, SmartGWT should handle cross domain requests on its own.

As a worst case scenario, you might have to send a JSONP style response along with required headers to get this working.
In that case, its probably best to have a separate method, similar to following, to serve SmartGWT requests.
I haven't worked with XJSONDataSource, so following is only a guideline.

```
// use a slightly different URI to distinguish from other controller method
@RequestMapping(value = "/invoiceId/sgwt", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody String getContactTypeByUserIdForSgwt(@RequestBody String invoiceNumber,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

     // can reuse normal controller method
     InvoiceDetailDTO invoiceDetailDto = getContactTypeByUserId(invoiceNumber);

     // use jackson or other tool to convert invoiceDetailDto to a JSON string
     String JSONstring = convertToJson(invoiceDetailDto);

    // will have to check SmartGWT request to make sure actual parameter name that send the callback name
    String callbackString = request.getParameter("callback"); 

    response.setContentType("text/X-JSON");

    return  callbackString + " ( " + JSONstring + " ) " ;
 }
```

---

### Update

Probably a good idea to clean up code (or start from scratch/minimum) due to left overs from previous efforts.

There are three phases in solving this:
 1. Get SmartGWT to work correctly, **without** using the service
 2. Get the service to work correctly with CORS requests
 3. Switch SmartGWT to use the service

Phase 1 should be used to iron out any client side issues.
Skip to phase 2, if client is working with the service when deployed in the same host/domain.

**Phase 1**
For this, its possible to use a data URL that provide a static response, as explained in [RestDataSource JSON responses](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/data/RestDataSource.html).
Place the sample response in a file similar to `test.json` and make it accessible from client web application.
Keep the DataSource code to a minimum and use `setDataURL();` with `test.json` location.

`test.json` - change (and add if needed) field names and values

```
{    
 response:{
    status:0,
    startRow:0,
    endRow:3,
    totalRows:3,
    data:[
        {field1:"value", field2:"value"},
        {field1:"value", field2:"value"},
        {field1:"value", field2:"value"},
    ]
 }
}
```

DataSource

```
public class TestDS extends RestDataSource {

    private static TestDS instance = new TestDS();

    public static TestDS getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private TestDS() {
        setDataURL("data/test.json");       // => http://<client-app-host:port>/<context>/data/test.json
        setDataFormat(DSDataFormat.JSON);
        // setClientOnly(true);

        DataSourceTextField field1 = new DataSourceTextField("field1", "Field 1");
        DataSourceTextField field2 = new DataSourceTextField("field2", "Field 2");

        setFields(field1, field2);
    }
}
```

**Phase 2**
Check references for additional details.

Headers of a **failed** preflight CORS request made from a page hosted in `localhost:8118`, and service hosted in `localhost:7117`.
Failed due to different port. Will fail on different scheme (https/ftp/file/etc.) or different host/domain as well.

```
Host: localhost:7117
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8118                   <= indicates origin to which access should be granted
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET              <= indicates the method that will be used in actual request
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type    <= indicates the headers that will be used in actual request

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
```

Request/response header pairs of a successful request.

```
Host: localhost:7117
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8118
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8118
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

Host: localhost:7117
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8118/cors-test.html
Origin: http://localhost:8118

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

In order to support CORS requests, service backend must respond correctly to the preflight OPTIONS request, not just the service call.
This can be done using a ServletFilter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>corsfilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>test.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>corsfilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8118");

            // list of allowed methods, Access-Control-Request-Method must be a subset of this
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
            // list of allowed headers, Access-Control-Request-Headers must be a subset of this
            response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, If-Modified-Since");

            // pre-flight request cache timeout
            // response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "60");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/values", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Map> getValues() {
    List<Map<String, Object>> values = getValues(); // handle actual data processing and return a list suitable for response

    SgwtResponse sgwtResponse = new SgwtResponse(); // A POJO with basic (public) attributes
    sgwtResponse.status = 0L;
    sgwtResponse.startRow = 0L;
    sgwtResponse.endRow = Long.valueOf(values.size());
    sgwtResponse.totalRows = sgwtResponse.startRow + sgwtResponse.endRow;
    sgwtResponse.data = values; // java.util.List

    Map<String, SgwtResponse> jsonData = new HashMap<String, SgwtResponse>();
    jsonData.put("response", sgwtResponse);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // required

    return new ResponseEntity<Map>(jsonData, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

A simple test page that use jQuery to retrieve a JSON response using XHR.
Change URL and deploy in client web application to directly test service, without using SmartGWT.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#retrieve").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        url: "<URL-of-service>",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            $("#content").text(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            $("#content").text("Unable to retrieve data");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="retrieve" value="Retrieve"/>
        <div id="content"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

`If-Modified-Since` header was required in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` for SmartGWT.
Use `RPCManager.setAllowCrossDomainCalls(true);` during SmartGWT initialization to avoid the warning.

Most modern browsers (Browser compatibility<sup>1</sup>) and SmartGWT **RestDataSource** support CORS requests.
Use XJSONDataSource only when you have to rely on JSONP, due to browser incompatibility with CORS requests.

Sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` for pre-flight request will allow any site to make cross domain calls to the service, which could pose a security issue, plus `*` can not be used in certain CORS requests.
Better approach is to specify the exact site to which cross domain requests are allowed - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.foo.com`.
Probably not required in this case, but check [Access-Control-Allow-Origin Multiple Origin Domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains) if needed, to find ways to allow multiple sites to make CORS requests.

References:
[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
[2] http://java-success.blogspot.com/2012/11/cors-and-jquery-with-spring-mvc-restful.html