# How to enable CORS in my site

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I have a WordPress site and I am getting an error from my website.
The error is Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at my site
how can I fix this problem??

Comment: Not exactly related, but check the 'Phase 2' section in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282825/2208271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend you to have a read through [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Infact that you are using wordpress you could simply create a proxy  code with php  and call the resource outside the domain with ajax

PLease have a look at the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23607901/cross-origin-request-blocked-on)